# How do I securely connect to a private mysql remote server and fetch data using R?

Tags: mysql, r, security, server, rmysql

I am working on writing an R package to submit to Bioconductor. It needs to fetch 4 databases from a remote mysql server. My question is, what is the right way to go about this with regard to the usernames and passwords, both for the host server and for mysql? So far I have been able to fetch the data by creating an SSH tunnel locally, using:

```
ssh -L 3307:localhost:3306 username@mycompany.org
```

And then running the following in R:

```
library(RMySQL)
library(dbConnect)
options(warn=-1)

getData <- function(){
  driver = dbDriver("MySQL");
  connection = dbConnect(driver, user='**', password='**', dbname='dbname', host='127.0.0.1',port=3307);
  assign("age",dbGetQuery(connection, statement= paste("select * from age")),.GlobalEnv);
  assign("biblio",dbGetQuery(connection, statement= paste("select * from biblio")),.GlobalEnv);
}
```

This fetches me the data I need. What would be the correct way to connect to the server, fetch the data, and then close the connection without exposing my server or passwords, since I want to submit this and publish eventually?

Comment: Why would you want to publish your own database credentials to a package which would be used by just about anybody?  In any case, R is a data analysis tool, not really an enterprise software tool.  So, it might be tricky to even do what you have in mind.

Comment: *"R is a data analysis tool, not really an enterprise software tool"* @TimBiegeleisen Some have extended R so it has scaling for enterprises things like  [RevoScaleR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/machine-learning-server/r-reference/revoscaler/revoscaler) and [Oracle R Enterprise](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/r/r-enterprise/overview/index.html)
 comes to mind..

Comment: @RaymondNijland When I commented, I was speaking of base R, and its original intended purpose.  It is also possible to execute a Java application from R, which is one way the OP could make a database call and obfuscate the credentials.

Comment: *"When I commented, I was speaking of base R, and its original intended purpose"* Fair enough  @TimBiegeleisen   back on topic.. The topicstarter should make a webservice or socket based server where the R client can connect to.. The webservice / socket server can acces the databases directly, the R client can acces the database by a protocol through the webservice / socket server ..

Comment: That sounds like an answer to me :-)

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I want to make the data public to everyone, via this R package. The issue is that it is all sitting on a private server and I need guidance on how to make it accessible by the general public without exposing the server. 
I work in genetics research, and want to create a tool for anyone who wants to access the data, much like easyPubMed and other bioinformatics packages.

@RaymondNijland could you please elaborate on the webserver/socket server a bit? That sounds like what I need to look into.